# Load image from Postgres into Report Builder 3.0

Tags: postgresql, reportbuilder

I've loaded an image directly into postgres and I know it's there as I can do lo-export and extract it. It's a .png in an OID column. I have a connection to postgres through report builder, which is successfully pulling data from my other tables. I can also use the image as an embedded image ok. However, when I use 'database' or 'external' as the image source and select the image field from my table, I only get a red cross when i run the report.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thinking through this, here are some things I think would be worth trying.  I cant find any discussion of this in the Report Builder 3.0 documentation which is not surprising since it is designed for SQL Server.  I would not be surprised if this unsupported.

1. Try storing as a bytea instead of as a lob.  The lob API is pretty complex and with bytea, all you have to worry about is text vs binary mode and whether the driver will unescape the results or not.
2. If it works as a bytea but not as a lob, then your issue is solely with the lob API.  Bytea should be fine for images and small files anyway.  It's only when you get to the point where seek() is helpful that lobs really shine.
3. If it does not work as bytea, then you may want to look at exporting the lob to your filesystem.  Take a look at the postgreSQL documentation for lo_export.

Comment: thanks for the help, in the end i thought it a better use of time to go to open source and am using Jasper instead